# Похудевший шрифт иврита, тайского и им подобных языков в консоли Linux

Tags: debian, консоль, шрифты

Собственно проблема в Debian 8 с отображением некоторых шрифтов в консоли: иврит, тайский и пр. Они выглядят меньше и тоньше своих кириллических и латинских аналогов. На примере фразы: Привет! !שלום Hello! สวัสดี!.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, здесь, в браузере Firefox v45, если поместить эту же фразу в **обратные кавычки**, то получим такой же результат, как и в терминале: `Привет! !שלום Hello! สวัสดี!`. Аналогично при просмотре в vim, gedit. В обычном же просмотре в браузере или в LibreOffice данные символы отображаются нормально.

Как это можно исправить, чтобы шрифты отображались в читабельном виде по аналогии с кириллицей?

#### Дополнение

В комментариях подсказали, что данный вопрос можно решить путём изменения шрифтов в настройках терминала, однако возникла следующая ситуация.

В font-manager подобрал шрифт, но при попытке применить его к терминалу, данный шрифт повёл себя некрасиво:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот как он стал отображаться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как на это можно повлиять?

Comment: Мне сейчас очень интересно: а зачем Вам это? :)

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить этот же текст в виде строки в вопрос?

Comment: 1- В зависимости от того что под словом консоль понимать, в общем случае, возможно используемый шрифт не имеет букв из иврита, поэтому подстановочный шрифт с другими свойствами используется (шрифт только подмножество символов может поддерживать).  2- Для не GUI консоли, [шрифт вообще может по кусочкам собираться](http://askubuntu.com/a/98750/3712). Попробуйте [поменять шрифт в консоли](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49779/1321). 3- не знаю, но возможно это [эффекты автоматического hinter для  букв, непохожих на латиницу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType#Linux_and_other_platforms) 4-...

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @jfs Вы правы, изменение шрифта в терминале решает проблему. Осталось подобрать компромиссный шрифт, отображающий нормально и кириллицу, и латиницу, и иврит.

Comment: @jfs оформите Ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Если вы думаете что нашли решение, то можете опубликовать его как свой ответ (чтобы помочь будущим посетителям с тем же вопросом)—[это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs частично, возникла новая проблема, некоторые шрифты терминал не отображает корректно, хотя в GUI версии они отображаются хорошо. Дополню в вопросе.

Comment: @edem запоздалый плюс от меня )

Answer (score 1):

Шрифты есть двух типов. Моноширинные, и обычные. Консоль **всегда** (так было раньше) использует **моноширинные** шрифты, в связи с тем, что пространство консоли разделено на сетку, внутри которой каждый символ занимает свою **конкретную** клеточку. Т.е. у каждой буквы есть конкретные координаты в сетке, где сетка квантуется на квадраты 8x8, 8х12, 8х14, 9х14. Ширина любой буквы не может быть **больше чем** 8 пикселей, **меньше чем** 8 пикселей. Но некоторые версии консоли позволяют "использовать" любой шрифт.

Консоль наследует понятие консоли из DOS, где символ задавался байтом, а шрифт находился отдельно, и имел фиксированый размер места под букву (8x8 изначально). Пример шрифта для dos http://shackmaster.narod.ru/fonts.htm.

Часть консольных программ заточена именно под сетку (например midnight commander, инсталятор linux и много консольных утилит) и изменив это правило, картинка просто посыпется. Поэтому отказатся от неё не получится.

Поэтому максимум что можно сделать:

- поискать более подходящий шрифт (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-terminal)
- подредактировать шрифт

но при этом не забывать про сетку.

Ещё, судя по вашей картинке, ваш шрифт не моноширинный, поэтому символы "выравниваются" влево, под сетку (поэтому более широкие символы выглядят более эстетично чем узкие). Нужно поставить моноширинный шрифт, там Console, или Courier New, например - это улучшит картинку.